# How to separate libraries according to target device?

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk

I'm developing an application for some devices with custom hardware, they are from different manufacturers but the purpose and logic at the application level are the same, each device has its SDK. Is it possible to filter each SDK according to the target device?

I was thinking something like preprocessors in C/C++, it's set a flag in the make file that you can query in code and filter some sections in the code.

Any idea how to handle something like this in Android?

## Update

#### The device

The device has some hardware features like a printer, LEDs, an EMV card reader. Something like this:

[image]

#### SDKs

Those SDKs are imported as modules in the project, the main project references them.

#### Interfaces

There's a set of abstract classes that define the common behavior like read a card, print a check, etc. On these behaviors, it's necessary to call specific functions according to each device. For example, each device from different vendors has a way to print an invoice.

#### What I would like to do.

The idea is to generate the APK just with the SDK required for each device and skip those implementations different from the target device.

#### Example with preprocessors.

```
#if defined(DEVICE1)
void printInvoice(char * msg){
   sdk_device1.print(msg);
}
#endif

#if defined(DEVICE2)
void printInvoice(char * msg){
   sdk_device2.print(msg);
}
#endif
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not enough information. Are SDKs sharing some interface that app knows about? Are SDKs available at compile or runtime? How do you consume SDKs?

Comment: Use product flavors, one flavor per hardware. Put the per-hardware code in the corresponding flavor's source set, implementing some common API that your code in `main` can reference.

Comment: @ror Thanks for your response, I added the details you requested :)

Comment: @CommonsWave Thanks for your suggestion, I'll have a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach the problem like this:

1. I'd define product flavors per hardware config
2. I'd associate proguard configurations for each given flavor, with minimal goal to strip whatever n-1 modules not needed, and leave last one specific for the hardware build is done for
3. I'd enable proguard for release builds

...after a bit of thinking:

4. You'd also need some sort of factory to give you instance of sdk for specific flavor (may be something similar to how we define testInstrumentationRunner).

If you are not using proguard in your solution (or whatever alternative to proguard), you will likely face issues introducing it, but in the end you'd still need it so time worth spending resolving them.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your response!. I'll start making some tests in an isolated project and see how this works.